# Is there any software on Windows 10 that will let you set a fixed speed for ripping a CD to MP3 format?

Tags: audio, windows-10, mp3, optical-media, ripping

Normally, I use iTunes when ripping an audio CD to MP3 format. However, I've run into a problem with one CD in my collection. The disc is clean and there are no discernable scratches. It's just very poorly balanced. When I try to rip it in iTunes, it causes so much vibration and noise that I was concerned it would destroy the CD and/or the drive hardware if allowed to proceed, so I immediately aborted the import and ejected the CD to make it stop. I looked in the iTunes import settings but could not find a way to force iTunes to play the CD at a fixed low speed (preferably 1X) when ripping it.

Is there a way to force iTunes to go slowly when ripping a CD? If not, is there another program on Windows 10 that will allow you to force the CD rip to MP3 to occur at low speed?

Answer (score 1):

[MusicBee](http://getmusicbee.com/) is a full featured portable music library and media player with ripping capabilities that runs on Windows 7 and newer.

It has among other features ripping capabilities using a myriad of third party or builtin libraries and methods. Under *Edit > Preferences > Ripping* you can set multiple options including a mode *Quick Rip* or *Secure* and also a selection of several speed settings.

[image]